# Why do alignment restrictions change the behaviour of clang while vectorising?

Tags: c++, clang, x86-64, memory-alignment, avx

Can anyone explain the behaviour of clang?

```
Array4Complex64 f1(Array4Complex64 a, Array4Complex64 b){
    return a * b;
}
```

This function calculates for each element in a and b the complex product. I compiled it twice once with alignment restrictions on the type Array4Complex64 and once without. the results are the following:

with alignment:

```
f1(Array4Complex64, Array4Complex64):               # @f1(Array4Complex64, Array4Complex64)
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -32
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     rax, rdi
    vmovapd ymm0, ymmword ptr [rbp + 80]
    vmovapd ymm1, ymmword ptr [rbp + 112]
    vmovapd ymm2, ymmword ptr [rbp + 16]
    vmovapd ymm3, ymmword ptr [rbp + 48]
    vmulpd  ymm4, ymm1, ymm3
    vfmsub231pd     ymm4, ymm0, ymm2        # ymm4 = (ymm0 * ymm2) - ymm4
    vmovapd ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm4
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm3, ymm0
    vfmadd231pd     ymm0, ymm1, ymm2        # ymm0 = (ymm1 * ymm2) + ymm0
    vmovapd ymmword ptr [rdi + 32], ymm0
    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

without:

```
f1(Array4Complex64, Array4Complex64):               # @f1(Array4Complex64, Array4Complex64)
    mov     rax, rdi
    vmovupd ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsp + 72]
    vmovupd ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsp + 104]
    vmovupd ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsp + 8]
    vmovupd ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsp + 40]
    vmulpd  ymm4, ymm1, ymm3
    vfmsub231pd     ymm4, ymm0, ymm2        # ymm4 = (ymm0 * ymm2) - ymm4
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm4
    vmulpd  ymm0, ymm3, ymm0
    vfmadd231pd     ymm0, ymm1, ymm2        # ymm0 = (ymm1 * ymm2) + ymm0
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rdi + 32], ymm0
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

The result is the same, but the addresses are calculated differently: once relative to rbp and once relative to rsp. It is not exclusive to multiplication and applies to any calculation. Is one version better than the other?

Comment: How did you provide these alignment restrictions? Is this through just a simple `alignas`? Also I'm a little confused by the assembly. The one you labeled as being with the alignment restrictions I would have assumed were for the unaligned one, since the first few instructions appear to computed a 32-bit-offset aligned boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is uselessly aligning RSP (and setting up RBP as a frame pointer in the process, so naturally it uses it). This is obviously a missed optimization since it's *not* actually spilling any of those function args to the stack.  (Since this is not a debug build).  You could report this to http://bugs.llvm.org/.  Include a MCVE of source code, and this asm output.

Both ways are unfortunately passing by value in stack memory, not YMM registers. :(  x86-64 System V can pass a struct in a YMM register if it's all FP and if it's 32 bytes in size.  (You might have to manually break your 64-byte args into two separate 32-byte args to pass efficiently, if you can't get this to inline, and you can't use AVX-512 to let it be passed in a single ZMM register.)

The caller is responsible for aligning RSP when passing an aligned object by value on the stack; stuff the callee does with RSP doesn't affect the address where the data is, and it's no copying it.

So clearly this is making this specific function less efficient, but **this function is so tiny you should *definitely* make sure this inlines into ever call site at which point all this overhead disappears.**  (Or at least the cost of unnecessarily aligning RSP is done once for a larger function, not once per call to a tiny function.)

The caller is having to run at least 4 `vmovapd` store instructions, and more than that around the call site, especially because x86-64 System V has no call-preserved ymm (or even xmm) registers.  So any other FP / vector variables or temporaries that were live in registers have to get spilled around a call to this function. And the call overhead itself takes the front-end some time, and some static code size.

The amount of code at every call-site for a non-inline version of this is probably similar to the amount of code it would take to just inline it!  This means inlining is pure win.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain the behaviour of clang?

Assuming that `Array4Complex64` is

```
using Array4Complex64 = double __attribute__ ((vector_size (64)));
```

which is a 512-bit type, it can be most efficient with avx512:

```
f1(double __vector(8), double __vector(8)):                           # @f1(double __vector(8), double __vector(8))
        vmulpd  zmm0, zmm0, zmm1
        ret
```

avx512 is, however, is not a portable technology and is often critisized for taking too much die size with very limited utility.

Comment: That's basically what I am doing I will have 5 implementations: AVX512, AVX, SSE, Neon and nothing. I just got the alignment by using the __m256d type. But since my server is my only CPU with AVX512 support, AVX512 support is lagging.